# How can I use Tailwind to size an SVG the same as an image in React/NextJS 13?

Tags: reactjs, svg, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I'm trying to create a modular UserProfilePhoto component in React that I can use anywhere a user's profile photo is shown.

In the default (empty) state, I want to display a generic user icon. That icon is a React component wrapping an SVG from Tailwind Heroicons. I am using tailwind css to size the items themselves.

Ultimately, the issue is that the SVG renders absurdly large, while an actual image is the size I want. I know this is because the `height` and `width` values I'm feeding the image are measured in pixels, but I've found NO way to actually correctly size the SVG to what I want. Before I modularized this component, it was just always the SVG and always the right size (styled with Tailwind), i.e. no Image component.

Here is the current iteration of the component:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { UserCircleIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/solid";

interface HasProfilePhoto {
  photo?: string;
}

type PhotoVariant = "mini" | "normal" | "preview";

type ProfilePhotoProps = {
  user?: HasProfilePhoto | null;
  variant?: PhotoVariant;
  emptyStyle?: string;
}

export function ProfilePhoto({ user, variant = "normal", emptyStyle = "text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400" }: ProfilePhotoProps) {
  const sizes = {
    mini: 32,
    normal: 40,
    preview: 96,
  }
  const size = sizes[variant];

  if (!user) return null;

  if (!user.photo) {
    // This is the bug!
    return (
      <div className={`flex rounded-full h-${size / 4} w-${size / 4} ${emptyStyle}`}>
        <UserCircleIcon className="w-full h-full" />
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <Image
      src={user.photo}
      alt=""
      width={size}
      height={size}
      className="rounded-full flex-none bg-gray-800 object-cover"
    />
  )
}
```

I've tried a number of other approaches, such as

```
<UserCircleIcon className="h-${size / 4} w-${size / 4}" />
```

```
<div className={`flex rounded-full h-${size / 4} w-${size / 4} ${emptyStyle}`}>
    <UserCircleIcon />
</div>
```

etc.

Nothing has made the SVG the same size as an image from the code beneath it, either way large or impossibly small.

The one way I've achieved the correct size unfortunately removed the ability for me to color the svg:

```
    const placeholderURL = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='currentColor' class='w-6 h-6'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M18.685 19.097A9.723 9.723 0 0021.75 12c0-5.385-4.365-9.75-9.75-9.75S2.25 6.615 2.25 12a9.723 9.723 0 003.065 7.097A9.716 9.716 0 0012 21.75a9.716 9.716 0 006.685-2.653zm-12.54-1.285A7.486 7.486 0 0112 15a7.486 7.486 0 015.855 2.812A8.224 8.224 0 0112 20.25a8.224 8.224 0 01-5.855-2.438zM15.75 9a3.75 3.75 0 11-7.5 0 3.75 3.75 0 017.5 0z' clip-rule='evenodd' /%3e%3c/svg%3e ";
    return (
      <Image
        src={placeholderURL}
        alt=""
        width={size}
        height={size}
        className="rounded-full bg-white"
      />
    )
```

Screenshots available but I don't have enough reputation here to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using the `style` attribute to apply `height` and `width` as appropriate, like:

```
<div
  className={`flex rounded-full ${emptyStyle}`}
  style={{ height, width }}
>
  <UserCircleIcon className="w-full h-full" />
</div>
```

Or

```
<UserCircleIcon style={{ height, width }} />
```

Comment: Gah, That's why it used to work - nothing was dynamic like this example shows. Thank you for the easy fix.